# Open DialogFragment from a Fragment - Error with FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

Hey i currently try to add a DialogFragment to a Fragment. It should open when i click on a TextView:

Fragment:

```
public class FragmentOneRm extends Fragment {



 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    myContext = (main_container)this.getActivity();

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) { mTextViewMaxWeight.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
 //other code         
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            DialogWeightConverter dialog = DialogWeightConverter.newInstance();
       // Problem with getFragmentManager() 
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "fragmentDialog");

        }
    });


    return view;
```

following error appears: Cannot resolve methode show(android.app.FragmentManager, java.lang.string)

Yes i know this question already excist but the solutions didnt work for me :/

my DialogFragment:

public class DialogWeightConverter extends DialogFragment {

```
Context mContext;

public DialogWeightConverter() {
    mContext = getActivity();
}


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();

    return dialog;
}

public static DialogWeightConverter newInstance() {
    DialogWeightConverter f = new DialogWeightConverter();
    return f;
} }
```

if you need more code from Project i will add it

thanks for help and greetings

Comment: make sure you are using one type of fragment every where, else it will be a problem. Use either support fragment i.e v4 fragment or normal app fragment

Comment: What's the specific problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DialogWeightConverter` extends from `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`? Try with `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`